# Comparing data sets with fade transitions (Code speed-up)

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic

I am using the utility below for data comparison.  However, with my real (more complex) charts the processing is quite slow, so setting the `Pause` time under `0.01` does not speed up the transition effect.  Quite a few frames are needed for a smooth transition.  I wonder if anyone can suggest ways to speed things up.

```
p1 = {{0.98, 1.02}, {1.29, 1.46}, {1.45, 1.8}, {1.69, 1.83},
   {2.01, 2.43}, {2.07, 2.43}, {2.39, 2.5}, {2.71, 2.99},
   {3.03, 3.51}, {3.33, 3.54}, {3.9, 3.91}, {4.2, 4.36},
   {4.46, 4.88}, {5.14, 4.62}, {5.48, 5.29}, {5.95, 5.96}};

p2 = {{1.04, 1.17}, {1.31, 1.61}, {1.51, 2.13}, {1.71, 2.06},
   {2.03, 2.61}, {2.15, 2.65}, {2.43, 2.65}, {2.61, 3.13},
   {2.95, 3.69}, {3.31, 3.84}, {3.92, 4.29}, {4.16, 4.69},
   {4.6, 5.14}, {5.14, 5.21}, {5.6, 5.66}, {5.99, 6.33}};

Deploy@Panel@DynamicModule[{op = 0, now = 0,
    a = ListPlot[p1, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}},
      PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Purple]],
    b = ListPlot[p2, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}},
      PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Blue]]},

   id = ImageDimensions@a;
   frames = 40;

   Column[{Row[{"Displayed data set:  ",
       Button["  p1  ", If[op == 1, now = 0;
         Do[op = Round[op - 1/frames, 0.001];
          FinishDynamic[]; Pause[0.01], {frames}]],
        Appearance -> Dynamic@If[op < 1 && now == 0, "Pressed", Automatic],
        ImageSize -> Medium],

       Button["  p2  ", If[op == 0, now = 1;
         Do[op = Round[op + 1/frames, 0.001];
          FinishDynamic[]; Pause[0.01], {frames}]],
        Appearance -> Dynamic@If[op > 0 && now == 1, "Pressed", Automatic],
        ImageSize -> Medium]}],

     Panel[Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, id],
        Inset[Dynamic@Insert[a, Opacity[Abs[op - 1]], {1, 1}], Center, Center, id],
        Inset[Dynamic@Insert[b, Opacity[op], {1, 1}], Center, Center, id]},
       PlotRange -> {{0, First@id}, {0, Last@id}}, ImageSize -> id],
      FrameMargins -> 15, Background -> White]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a good case to demonstrate how inefficient could the magic of Dynamic be.  Evaluating the code below shows how many times Dynamic refreshes your plot.  Click on the buttons to see.

```
p1 = {{0.98, 1.02}, {1.29, 1.46}, {1.45, 1.8}, {1.69, 1.83}, {2.01, 
    2.43}, {2.07, 2.43}, {2.39, 2.5}, {2.71, 2.99}, {3.03, 
    3.51}, {3.33, 3.54}, {3.9, 3.91}, {4.2, 4.36}, {4.46, 
    4.88}, {5.14, 4.62}, {5.48, 5.29}, {5.95, 5.96}};

p2 = {{1.04, 1.17}, {1.31, 1.61}, {1.51, 2.13}, {1.71, 2.06}, {2.03, 
    2.61}, {2.15, 2.65}, {2.43, 2.65}, {2.61, 3.13}, {2.95, 
    3.69}, {3.31, 3.84}, {3.92, 4.29}, {4.16, 4.69}, {4.6, 
    5.14}, {5.14, 5.21}, {5.6, 5.66}, {5.99, 6.33}};

Deploy@Panel@
  DynamicModule[{op = 0, now = 0, 
    a = ListPlot[p1, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Purple]], 
    b = ListPlot[p2, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Blue]], dCnt = 0}, 
   id = ImageDimensions@a;
   frames = 40;
   Column[{Row[{"Displayed data set:  ", 
       Button["  p1  ", If[op == 1, now = 0;
         Do[op = Round[op - 1/frames, 0.001];
          FinishDynamic[]; Pause[0.01], {frames}]];
        Print["Total Dynamic updates ", dCnt];, 
        Appearance -> 
         Dynamic@If[op < 1 && now == 0, "Pressed", Automatic], 
        ImageSize -> Medium], Button["  p2  ", If[op == 0, now = 1;
         Do[op = Round[op + 1/frames, 0.001];
          FinishDynamic[]; Pause[0.01], {frames}]]; 
        Print["Total Dynamic updates ", dCnt], 
        Appearance -> 
         Dynamic@If[op > 0 && now == 1, "Pressed", Automatic], 
        ImageSize -> Medium]}], 
     Panel[Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, id], 
        Inset[Dynamic[dCnt++; 
          Insert[a, Opacity[Abs[op - 1]], {1, 1}]], Center, Center, 
         id], Inset[Dynamic[dCnt++; Insert[b, Opacity[op], {1, 1}]], 
         Center, Center, id]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, First@id}, {0, Last@id}}, ImageSize -> id], 
      FrameMargins -> 15, Background -> White]}]]
```

There are many ways in which you could address your problem to improve speed, but regarding Dynamic, the most important thing is to make sure it only updates when appropriate.  For that I suggest using a counter, TrackingSymbols, and SynchronousUpdating as demonstrated in the next example.

```
p1 = {{0.98, 1.02}, {1.29, 1.46}, {1.45, 1.8}, {1.69, 1.83}, {2.01, 
    2.43}, {2.07, 2.43}, {2.39, 2.5}, {2.71, 2.99}, {3.03, 
    3.51}, {3.33, 3.54}, {3.9, 3.91}, {4.2, 4.36}, {4.46, 
    4.88}, {5.14, 4.62}, {5.48, 5.29}, {5.95, 5.96}};

p2 = {{1.04, 1.17}, {1.31, 1.61}, {1.51, 2.13}, {1.71, 2.06}, {2.03, 
    2.61}, {2.15, 2.65}, {2.43, 2.65}, {2.61, 3.13}, {2.95, 
    3.69}, {3.31, 3.84}, {3.92, 4.29}, {4.16, 4.69}, {4.6, 
    5.14}, {5.14, 5.21}, {5.6, 5.66}, {5.99, 6.33}};

Deploy@Panel@
  DynamicModule[
   {op = 0, now = 0, 
    a = ListPlot[p1, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Purple]], 
    b = ListPlot[p2, PlotRange -> {{0, 7}, {0, 7}}, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Blue]], refreshCnt = 0
    } 
   ,
   id = ImageDimensions@a;
   frames = 40;
   Column[{
     Row[{"Displayed data set:  ",
       Button["  p1  ",
        If[op == 1,
         now = 0;
         Do[op = Round[op - 1/frames, 0.001];, {frames}]
         ];
        refreshCnt++;
        Print["Total Dynamic updates ", refreshCnt]
        , Method -> "Queued"
        , 
        Appearance -> 
         Dynamic@If[op < 1 && now == 0, "Pressed", Automatic]
        , ImageSize -> Medium
        ]
       ,
       Button["  p2  ",
        If[op == 0,
         now = 1;
         Do[op = Round[op + 1/frames, 0.001], {frames}]
         ];
        refreshCnt++;
        Print["Total Dynamic updates ", refreshCnt]
        , Method -> "Queued"
        , 
        Appearance -> 
         Dynamic@If[op > 0 && now == 1, "Pressed", Automatic]
        , ImageSize -> Medium
        ]}]
     ,
     Panel[
      Dynamic[Refresh[
        Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{0, 0}, id], 
          Inset[Insert[a, Opacity[Abs[op - 1]], {1, 1}], Center, 
           Center, id], 
          Inset[Insert[b, Opacity[op], {1, 1}], Center, Center, id]}, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, First@id}, {0, Last@id}}, ImageSize -> id]
        , TrackedSymbols -> {refreshCnt}]
       ]
      , FrameMargins -> 15, Background -> White
      ]
     }]]
```